# Executing a startup script when docker container is up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I built a docker image with Dockerfile as below.
Everything's okay except but *RUN php /var/www/api/startup.php*
This PHP code is simple, just an API request to get some data from outside server.

When I run this image, it works well but I get into the container and see the created file:ocr_url.json.. saying "error!!!".

When I run the php code in docker container in person, it works fine.
So I checked the ENV variable: $SERVER. it returns "server-1" that I set in docker-compose.yml.

What's wrong? Does it execute PHP code before I get the ENV variable?
Please help me through this problem. thanks

```
<?php

//echo $server = $_ENV['SERVER'];
$server = getenv('SERVER');

if($server) {
        $url = "https://{url}/?server=$server";

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        //save to json file
        $file = fopen("ocr_url.json","w");
        fwrite($file, $resp);
        fclose($file);
}
else {
        $file = fopen("ocr_url.json","w");
        fwrite($file, 'error!!!');
        fclose($file);
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM server:v1.0

#startup program
CMD /root/startup.sh 
RUN php /var/www/api/startup.php

WORKDIR /var/www/api
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server1:
    image: '5318a9bfda5e'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:7771:80'
    environment:
      - 'SERVER=server-1'
  server2:
    image: '5318a9bfda5e'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:7772:80'
    environment:
      - 'SERVER=server-2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the order you have things in the Dockerfile, a `RUN` command always runs during the image build sequence, not at container startup, and it can never call out to other services.  It also doesn't get to see Compose `environment:` settings or anything else outside a `build:` block.  Whatever the output of the `RUN` command is will get compiled into the image, and since you're running the same image for both containers, they'll have the same downloaded file.

An entrypoint wrapper script might be a good match for this setup.  When the container starts, make its main process be a script that first does the download from the other container, then runs the standard container `CMD`.  The script could look like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Download the file from elsewhere
php /var/www/api/startup.php
# (or consider writing it as a half-dozen lines of shell code)

# Run the main container process (from the Dockerfile CMD for example)
exec "$@"
```

Then in your Dockerfile, `COPY` this script in and make it be the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
FROM server:v1.0

WORKDIR /var/www/api
# COPY entrypoint.sh .         # from the base image?
# RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh   # Docker preserves permissions from the host

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD /root/startup.sh           # unmodified from original Dockerfile
```

The file won't get downloaded during the image build, but if you launch a debugging shell

```sh
docker-compose run server1 sh
```

you will it will first download the file via the entrypoint script before launching the `sh` command.